# How does name mangling work when accessing `__attr` inside the class?

Tags: python, oop, name-mangling

I know what data mangling in Python is in general and what its purpose is, but there is one subtle aspect I would like to clarify.

Let's say we have a class:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.__y = 20
    
    def get_y(self):
        return self.__y
```

`p = P(); p.__dict__` now has the key `_P__y` so this is where the data mangling occurred.

My question is, though, how do we access the attribute inside `get_y` given that there is no `__y` key in `__dict__`?

I have a faint guess that there is some magic going on in `__getattribute__` and then, after getting `AttributeError`, in `__getattr__`.

This confusion makes me think that I don't have a 100% understanding of what `__init__` does under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name mangling is performed by the compiler, not at runtime. Specifically, in CPython, all the generated byte code assumes that the name of the attribute is `_P__y`, whenever `__y` occurs as an attribute in the `class` statement or a function defined inside the `class` statement.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(P)
Disassembly of __init__:
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              4 STORE_ATTR               0 (x)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (20)
              8 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             10 STORE_ATTR               1 (_P__y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of get_y:
  7           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_P__y)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Name mangling also occurs in almost any context whatsoever inside the class statement, even including stuff like global variable names, but using name mangling for weird stuff is a bad idea.

Comment: @chepner, thanks! This, roughly speaking, means that there is no trying to access a non-existent attribute because, during the compilation stage, all references to `__y` are replaced by `_P__y`. Is my understanding accurate?

Comment: Basically. The compiler only uses the names to distinguish between distinct values. Note that even `_P__y` isn't used *literally*; it has been replaced by an index into a table of "cells" that the compiler has determined are used in particular context. For example, `__y/_P__y` becomes attribute 1 in `__init__`, but is attribute 0 in `get_y`.

Comment: @chepner, this might be unrelated to the current question, but how come they have different indexes for `__init__` and `get_y`? 
Why not have it in this table once because all references to `__y` should be mapped to the same thing.

Comment: The indices are specific to the function being defined. `x` appears first, so it gets the first slot.